# Scraping this site

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im trying to mimic this `POST request` from this site with this `payload`:

from this URL: https://surviv.io/stats/gert1

Here is an image of the request im trying to `mimic`.
[image]

Here is my current code in python:

```py
import requests
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
url = 'https://surviv.io/api/user_stats'
payload = {"slug":"gert1","interval":"all","mapIdFilter":"-1"}
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(r.content)
```

This returns:

```
b'<html>\r\n<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

This is not what I want it return. I want it to return the exact response shown in the response tab of the `user_stats` requests, which contains the player's stats.

This is what I want it to return:

```py
{"slug":"gert1","username":"GERT","player_icon":"","banned":false,"wins":61,"kills":2830,"games":2034,"kpg":"1.4","modes":[{"teamMode":1,"games":1512,"wins":46,"kills":2230,"winPct":"3.0","mostKills":21,"mostDamage":1872,"kpg":"1.5","avgDamage":169,"avgTimeAlive":92},{"teamMode":2,"games":255,"wins":4,"kills":234,"winPct":"1.6","mostKills":8,"mostDamage":861,"kpg":"0.9","avgDamage":162,"avgTimeAlive":102},{"teamMode":4,"games":267,"wins":11,"kills":366,"winPct":"4.1","mostKills":17,"mostDamage":2225,"kpg":"1.4","avgDamage":246,"avgTimeAlive":125}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the json attribute rather than data in the post method. `r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=payload)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following your forgot to use `json` :

```
import json
import requests
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
url = 'https://surviv.io/api/user_stats'
payload = {"slug":"gert1","interval":"all","mapIdFilter":"-1"}
r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks. Why did my code not work if the data is not json. Does the data parameter always have to be in json

Comment: Yeah it always have to be since you provided content-type  as application/json.